# I need to check Table structure with triggers, constraints

Tags: sql, oracle, dll, triggers

I need to check complete DLL. I need a sql query for the same.

If I use `DESC` or `DESCRIBE` in Oracle, it shows me all columns and type.

But I also need all `Constraints`, `Triggers` acting on it, etc. Just like how Oracle SQL Developer shows the structure if you click on `SQL` tab.

What should be my query command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table definition with constraints:

```
select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', 'MY_TABLE' )
 from dual;
```

The triggers on table:

```
select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TRIGGER',trigger_name) from user_triggers where table_name='MY_TABLE';
```

Comment: I need to Spool this data on to a .txt file. But have some error, it doesn't export the complete picture on to my txt file?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35983994/oracle-spool-missing-complere-information

Answer (score 1):

For constraints:

```
Select constraint_name from all_constraints where table_name='Table_Name';
```

For triggers:

```
select trigger_name from all_triggers where table_name='Table_Name';
```

Comment: Any sql which can provide me complete DLL ?

Answer (score 0):

The `DBMS_METADATA` package is usually the best way to retrieve object DDL.

Retrieving *all* the DDL is a challenge because there are so many different types of DDL.  Use [this long list of object types](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_metada.htm#BGBIEDIA) from the PL/SQL Packages and Types Reference to choose the necessary types.  There are many ways to format the results and exclude different settings.

It's easy to spend a large amount of time on this seemingly simple task.  This is one reason why the tables should "live" in version controlled text files, not the database.  You'll find it's almost impossible to consistently get the exact same results from databases using `DBMS_METADATA` and similar methods.

**Sample Schema**

```
create table test1(a number, constraint test1_pk primary key (a));
create or replace trigger trigger1 before insert on test1
begin
    null;
end;
/
grant select on test1 to system;
```

**Code to Extract DDL**

```
declare
    v_clob clob;
begin
    --Add a semicolon at the end of each statement.
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'SQLTERMINATOR', true);
    --Get DDL.
    v_clob := v_clob || dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'TEST1', user);
    v_clob := v_clob || dbms_metadata.get_dependent_ddl('TRIGGER', 'TEST1', user);
    v_clob := v_clob || dbms_metadata.get_dependent_ddl('OBJECT_GRANT', 'TEST1', user);
    --Print DDL (or insert it, save it to a file, etc.)
    dbms_output.put_line(v_clob);
end;
/
```

**Results**

```
  CREATE TABLE "JHELLER"."TEST1" 
   (    "A" NUMBER, 
     CONSTRAINT "TEST1_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("A")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
  CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER "JHELLER"."TRIGGER1" before insert on test1
begin
    null;
end;

/
ALTER TRIGGER "JHELLER"."TRIGGER1" ENABLE;
  GRANT SELECT ON "JHELLER"."TEST1" TO "SYSTEM";
```